# Task.ContinueWith confusion

Tags: asynchronous, task, .net-4.5, async-await

With ASP.NET 4.5 I'm trying to play with the new async/await toys. I have a IDataReader-implementing class that wraps a vendor-specific reader (like SqlDatareader). I have a simple ExecuteSql() method that operates synchronously like so:

```
public IDataReader ReaderForSql(string sql)
{
    var cmd = NewCommand(sql, CommandType.Text);
    return DBReader.ReaderFactory(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
```

What I want is an Async version of this. Here's my first try:

```
public Task<IDataReader> ReaderForSqlAsync(string sql, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var cmd = NewCommand(sql, CommandType.Text);
    return cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(ct)
              .ContinueWith(t => DBReader.ReaderFactory(t.Result));
}
```

and I use it:

```
using (var r = await connection.ReaderForSqlAsync("SELECT ...", cancellationToken))
{
    ...
}
```

This works great in my limited testing so far. But after watching this Cloud9 video a few times: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET I got worreid about warnings they gave regarding:

- ContinueWith consuming extra threadpool resources - Readerfactory is very light!
- Task.Result blocking

and since I am passing a ContinuationToken to ExecuteReaderAsync() it seems cancellation is just yet another reason ExecuteReaderAsync() could fail (it's SQL after all!)

What will be the state of the task when I try to ContinueWith it? Will t.Result block? throw? do the wrong thing?

Comment: +1 for the awesome title. "Task.ContinueWith confusion". (also you made a very good post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ContinueWith` will use the current task scheduler (a thread pool thread) by default, but you can change that by passing `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` and an explicit `TaskScheduler`.

That said, I would make this as a first effort:

```
public async Task<IDataReader> ReaderForSqlAsync(string sql, CancellationToken ct)
{
  var cmd = NewCommand(sql, CommandType.Text);
  var readerResult = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
  return DBReader.ReaderFactory(readerResult);
}
```

`async` and `await` handle all the `ContinueWith` delicacies and edge conditions in a consistent manner for you. It may be possible to complicate this code to be faster **if** performance testing indicates it's a serious problem.

Comment: Are you using .ConfigureAwait(false) because the caller of ReaderForSqlAsync() is already awaiting it?

Comment: No. It's a best practice for methods that do not require a context, [as I describe on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: That blog post is EXACTLY what I needed Stephen - thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`Result` blocks if the task has not completed. But in the continuation handler it already has. So it does not block. You are doing the right thing.

When you invoke `Result` on a faulted task (and you say this might happen) the exception is rethrown. This causes your continuation to fault with the same exception which causes the final task returned from `ReaderForSqlAsync` to also be faulted. This is a good thing: The entire chain of tasks faulted and all exceptions have been observed (on contrast to being swallowed). So this is best-practice, too.

Using a thread for compute-bound work is always ok. So again, you are doing the right thing using ContinueWith. You have to compute the `IDataReader` *somewhere* after all. You cannot not compute it.

Comment: Thank you! What are you thoughts on .ContinueWith consuming threadpool resources?

Comment: Be it a manually started thread or a threadpool thread, it doesn't matter. When you execute code - any code at all - you are consuming a thread. So that's ok. Async aims to avoid *blocking*, but not computation. So this is perfectly ok and there is no better way (what could be a better way in your mind?).

Comment: `Result` doesn't rethrow the exception; it wraps it in `AggregateException`. This is one reason I discourage using `Result`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I guess you mean discourage in case await is available. I agree. If the OP is not on C# 5, though, it becomes complicated to work around this. If it is even required.

Comment: @usr: Yes; I only discourage `Result` if `await` is available. :)

Comment: @stephen cleary: I AM on C#5 and my intention is to await on this. I am trying to coordinate the async-execution of SQL with the wrapping of the result, all so the caller can await on it. If ContinueWith isn't executed until the thread completes why is .Result bad?

Comment: `Result` will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`; this makes error handling much more troublesome than using `await`.