# "await"-able APIs

Tags: c#, asynchronous, c#-5.0

I am adding Async capabilities to an API. I have this interface:

```
public interface IThing
{
    bool Read();
    Task<bool> ReadAsync();
}
```

Callers can use it async like so:

```
using (IThing t = await GetAThing())
{
    while (await t.ReadyAsync();
    {
        // do stuff w/the current t
    }
}
```

There is a class that implements IThing:

```
public class RealThing : IThing
{
    public bool Read()
    {
        // do a synchronous read like before
    }

    public Task<bool> ReadAsync()
    {
        return _internal.ReadAsync(); // This returns a Task<bool>
    }
}
```

This compiles and works! But other examples prefer this implementation for ReadAsync():

```
public async Task<bool> ReadAsync()
{
    return await _internal.ReadAsync();
}
```

Given that the caller will be awaiting, why the async/await in the API?

Comment: What does your internal `ReadAsync()` implementation look like?

Comment: Shouldn't `IThing` extend `IDisposable` if you want it to always be used in a `using`?  If it isn't actually a disposable resource then it shouldn't be used in a `using` to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public async Task<bool> ReadAsync()
{
  return await _internal.ReadAsync();
}
```

There's no need for that. It only adds overhead and does not provide any benefit.

Your code is better:

```
public Task<bool> ReadAsync()
{
  return _internal.ReadAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen - I did that becuase of your example in answering my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651383/task-continuewith-confusion. Is that becuase I had stuff going on AFTER the task completed?

Comment: @n8wrl Correct, that is what prevented him from doing this in that other example.

Comment: I see - and the await machinery is safer than .ContinueWith(). Got it! Thank you!

Comment: @n8wrl I wouldn't say that it's safer, but it's usually simpler.